# Flask + DataTables: how do you read the AJAX request that DataTables sends as JSON?

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, flask

I've created a Flask application which:

- Reads events from different event sources;
- Persists those events to database; and
- Allows users to search through those events using DataTables 1.10.20.

I'm trying to:

- Read the parameters that DataTables is passing to the Flask backend via an AJAX request whenever a user attempts to search through the table; and
- Translate those parameters into a dictionary so they can be used when performing server-side filtering.

Here is the code for the table I created in DataTables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    events_table_template = {
        "scrollX": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/ajax/events",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc": "data",
            "contentType": "application/json"
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "event_id"},
            {"data": "event_type"},
            {"data": "event_timestamp"},
            {"data": "event_name"},
        ]
    };
    var table = $('#events-table').DataTable(events_table_template);
});
```

I've tried explicitly returning JSON within the DataTables configuration:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    events_table_template = {
...
    "ajax": {
...
        "data": function(args){
            return {"args": JSON.stringify(args)};
        }
    };
    var table = $('#events-table').DataTable(events_table_template);
});
```

Here is the AJAX endpoint on the Flask server:

```
from mycode import EventService
from flask import Blueprint

import flask

blueprint = Blueprint('events-ajax', __name__, url_prefix='/ajax/')


@blueprint.route('/events/', methods=["POST"])
def get_events():
    print("Request data", flask.request.data)
    print("Request form", flask.request.form)

    api = EventService()
    events = api.get_events_via_database()

    rows = []
    for event in api.get_events_via_database():
        rows.append({
            'event_id': event.event_id,
            'event_type': event.type,
            'event_timestamp': event.timestamp,
            'event_name': event.name,
        })

    response = {
        'data': rows,
        'recordsTotal': len(events),
        'recordsFiltered': len(events),
        'draw': 1,
    }
    return flask.jsonify(response)
```

I've noticed that:

- `flask.request.data` returns a bunch of URL encoded text: `Request data b'draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=event_id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=host_id&columns%5B1%5D%5B...`
- `flask.request.form` returns an `ImmutableMultiDict` object: `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

I've tried to:

- Read the content of the AJAX request using these functions:

  - `flask.request.data`
  - `flask.request.form`
  - `flask.request.json`
  - `flask.request.get_json(force=True)`
- Change the `content-type` from the DataTables side of things from `application/json` to `application/json; charset=utf-8`

How do you read the AJAX request as JSON?

Answer (score 3):

- Remove `"contentType": "application/json"` from the `"ajax"` configuration block; and
- Use `flask.request.form` to read the map of parameters present within the AJAX request.

**DataTables**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    events_table_template = {
        "scrollX": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/ajax/events",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc": "data",
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "event_id"},
            {"data": "event_type"},
            {"data": "event_timestamp"},
            {"data": "event_name"},
        ]
    };
    var table = $('#events-table').DataTable(events_table_template);
});
```

**Flask**:

```
@blueprint.route('/events/', methods=["POST"])
def get_events():
    parameters = dict(flask.request.form)
```